# JSTL call a method that's not a setter or a getter

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

i have these method in a class:

```
 public HarfDate getHarfTo() {
        return to;
      }
```

i just wonder how to call it in JSTL as i tried to call it like that:

```
${exam.getHarfTo()}
```

but it doesn't work!!

Note: exam is an instance of the class enclosing these method

- to is not a static member inside the class if the solution is to make the method static

Comment: Alex Theedom's reply is correct in this particular case. But I'm curious: what is the servlet specification number defined in your web.xml? If it is below 2.5, try setting it to 2.5 and trying again. I believe that it SHOULD be possible to invoke methods from an EL expression since the 2.5 servlet specification.

Comment: did you got the answer?? Cause I'm facing the same problem.....

Answer (score 9):

The instance of the `exam` object must be within an EL scope such as `pageScope`. Assuming that the `exam` object reference is refered to in the pageScope as "exam" then the following EL will call the `getHarfTo` method:

```
   ${exam.harfTo}
```

NOTE: you cannot call a setter method.

To expand on the above (and just as an example) we can set the `exam` instance in the `pageScope` using scriptlets (note that scriptlets are not recommened this is just an example for clarification)

```
    <%
        com.example.Exam exam = new com.example.Exam();
        pageContext.setAttribute("exam", exam, PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
    %>
```

now we can access the exam object via EL: ${exam.harfTo}

The exam object can be added to other scopes such as the request scope and the session scope.

**Scriptlets and EL**

```
   <%
        java.util.ArrayList cities = new java.util.ArrayList();
        cities.add("NYC");
        cities.add("SFO");
   %>
```

Variables created in a scriptlet are not directly accessible to EL. Thus, the cities variable cannot be used in JSTL tags.

To do so, we first need to put it in some scope. For example:

```
    <%
        java.util.ArrayList cities = new java.util.ArrayList();
        cities.add("NYC");
        cities.add("SFO");
        pageContext.setAttribute("cities", cities, PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
    %>
```

This makes the object referred to by cities variable, available in the `pageScope` by the name of "cities".

```
    <select name="Cities">
           <c:forEach var="city" items ="${cities}">
                  <option> ${city}</option>
           </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

The cities variable can now be accessed.
You cannot have a scriptlet as the property of an EL expression.

```
    <select name="Cities">
           <%for(int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++) {%>
           <option>${cities[<%=i%>]}</option>
           <%}%>
    </select>
```

or you can use **Standard actions** if the exam class conforms to bean conventions:

```
    <jsp:useBean id="exam" class="com.example.Exam" scope="pageScope"/>
    The value return by the method called harfTo: <jsp:getProperty name="exam" property="harfTo"/>
```

Dont forget to import the JSTL tag lib:

```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix ="c" %>
```

EDIT:

If you have a collection `exams` which contains `exam` objects then you can use JSTL to iterate over then collection like so:

```
 <c:forEach var="exam" items ="${exams}">
         ${exam.harfTo}
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: exam is an id of a display table that loops over a collection of the exam object

Answer (score 1):

To access the method, you just strip off the get part.

```
${exam.harfTo}
```

The same works if you want to call a class's setter method.

Answer (score 1):

You need a TLD to do what you intend.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31614/JSP-JSTL-Custom-Tag-Library) link has a really elaborate example .

HTH